# Depends on vulnerable versions of json5

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, webpack, breeze

I am trying to install new version(8.83.27) of Laravel with breeze.
Did these steps and I got error while installing npm

```
    php artisan breeze:install vue
     
    php artisan migrate
    npm install
```

Output:

```
> Will install laravel-mix@0.8.9, which is a breaking change
> node_modules/img-loader/node_modules/json5
> node_modules/vue-style-loader/node_modules/json5   loader-utils 
> <=1.4.2   Depends on vulnerable versions of json5  
> node_modules/img-loader/node_modules/loader-utils  
> node_modules/vue-style-loader/node_modules/loader-utils
>     img-loader  *
>     Depends on vulnerable versions of loader-utils
>     node_modules/img-loader
>       laravel-mix  >=0.9.0
>       Depends on vulnerable versions of img-loader
>       Depends on vulnerable versions of vue-style-loader
>       node_modules/laravel-mix
>     vue-style-loader  *
>     Depends on vulnerable versions of loader-utils
>     node_modules/vue-style-loader
> 
> 5 high severity vulnerabilities
```

Comment: laravel-mix is *not* at version 0.8 or something. It's at version 6 or something like that. can you show your `package.json`?

Comment: I don't know what was the problem but I created new project with 
composer create-project laravel/laravel:^8.0 example-app and it works now but when I do just composer create-project laravel/laravel I got errors and I can't run npm.

Comment: update your original question with the errors you are getting. Find the errors in your laravel.log and copy/paste the entire stacktrace of those errors. I cannot guess which errors you are getting